# How to interpret hausman test results?

Tags: regression, python, instrumental-variables, hausman, statsmodels

I'm trying to do 2 stage least squares regression in python using the statsmodels library.

```
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm import IV2SLS                       
resultIV = IV2SLS(dietdummy['Log Income'], dietdummy.drop(['Log Income', 'Diabetes']),     
dietdummy.drop(['Log Income', 'Reads Nutri')
```

`Reads Nutri` is my endogenous variable my instrument is `Diabetes` and my dependent variable is `Log Income`.

Can someone explain to me how I interpret Hausman statistic results. In my case `resultIV.spec_hausman()` gives me this output: `(0.11839130964519647, 0.99999585620023634, 7)`

Comment: Your question about how to interpret the Hausman statistic is on topic here, but questions about how to use Python are not. You may want to edit that part to reflect any statistical questions you may have about 2SLS.

Comment: @gung, done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2SLS model you fitted can be written as:

$$lnincome_i=\beta_0+\beta_1ReadsNutri_i'+\gamma\widehat{ReadsNutri_i}+\epsilon_i $$

where $\widehat{ReadsNutri_i}$ was predicted using

$$ReadsNutri_i=\delta_0+\delta_1Diabetes_i+\nu_i$$

The Hausman test in 2SLS tests whether the coefficient on $\widehat{ReadsNutri_i}$ is statistically significant or not, with the null hypothesis being $H_0: \gamma=0$.  It is a test of whether OLS estimates are significantly different from the instrumental variable (IV) estimates.  If $\gamma=0$, you can conclude that there is no evidence of endogeneity of $ReadsNutri$ in the sample, since $\gamma \ne 0$ when $ReadsNutri$ is endogenous.  The 2SLS estimator is still consistent even if the variable was exogenous, but the IV estimator can be less efficient than OLS, which is why we generally report OLS results in the absence of endogeneity (Cameron and Trivedi, 2009).  Of course you should also be sure you have both theoretical and empirical justification for the instrument you have chosen when you use an IV estimator.

Going back to your question about the interpretation of `(0.11839130964519647, 0.99999585620023634, 7)`, [the documentation for Statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/_modules/statsmodels/sandbox/regression/gmm.html) (screengrab of relevant part of the source code pasted below) appears to show that `spec_hausman()` spits out the following values: the Hausman test statistic ($T_H$), the p-value, and the degrees of freedom.  If this is the case, then the output shows that $T_H$=0.118, *p*=0.999, which means there is no evidence of endogeneity of $ReadsNutri$ in your sample.  For future reference, I urge you to check the documentation of the function you are using so that you understand what is being outputted by the package.

[image: source code for spec_hausman()]

---

**References**

1. Cameron, A. C., & Trivedi, P. K. (2009). Microeconometrics Using
   Stata. Microeconometrics Using Stata. College Station, TX, USA:
   Stata Press.
2. Perktold, J., Seabold, S., & Taylor, J. (2013). Source code for
   statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm. Retrieved from
   http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/_modules/statsmodels/sandbox/regression/gmm.html